# GroupBy Method Changing DataType

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Using Python3 and Anaconda, I have pandas and os imported on ipython. I have an extremely large csv file. After using read_csv on the file, I try to use .groupby() on two columns, but it changes the data type from DataFrame to DataFrameGroupBy, and I can no longer run data frame methods on it.

I can't think of anything to try. I have very little experience with pandas, gained through codecademy. My code appears to work there.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

totals = pd.read_csv('filename')

band_gaps = totals.groupby(['column1','column2'])

band_gaps.info()
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'info' of 
'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

type(band_gaps)
pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy
```

I expect that when I run band_gaps.info(), it provides me with the info for the data frame. Instead, it gives me an error. When I check band_gaps' type, it is no longer a dataframe, and is instead a DataFrameGroupBy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Pandas groupby documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) you'll see that it returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` or `SeriesGroupBy` object, depending on whether you called `.groupby` on a `DataFrame` or a `Series`. So the behavior you've observed shouldn't be surprising.

More importantly, why does Pandas do that? Well, in your case you're grouping a bunch of rows together. Pandas can hold on to some representation of the grouped `DataFrame`, but it can't do anything else with it (ie, return it to you as another `DataFrame`) until you apply an aggregation function like `.sum` or `.count`. An aggregation function takes each group of rows and defines some way of turning that row into a single row. Try applying one of those aggregation functions to `band_gaps` and see what happens.

For example:

```
df.groupby('column1').mean()
```

will return a `DataFrame` expressing the mean of every column after grouping all rows by `column1`.

```
df.groupby('column1')['column2'].sum()
```

will return a `Series` with the sum of the values in `column2` after grouping by `column1`. Note that

```
df.groupby('column1').sum()['column2']
```

may also be possible, but in that case you're taking the column you're interested in after you've aggregated over all columns, which is slower than slicing before aggregating.